# structure and properties of a function inherited from its integrals

Tags: integration, general-topology, geometry, monotone-functions

Let $f:[0,1]^2 \rightarrow \{0,1\}$, $f_B(b) = \int_0^1 f(b, s)\; ds$ and $f_S(s) = \int_0^1 f(b, s)\; db$, such that $f_B$ is non-decreasing and $f_S$ is non-increasing. What can we infer about $f$ from the monotonicity of $f_B$ and $f_S$?

For instance, the following class of functions satisfies the monotonicity  constraints
\begin{align*}
f(b,s) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & s \leq g(b)\\
0 & otherwise
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
for some non-decreasing function $g$.

Another class of functions which satisfies the monotonicity constraints can be constructed using the set

$A = \{(b, s) \in [0,1]^2\mid g_1(b) \geq s \geq g_2(b), g_1'(b) = g_2'(b) >0, g_2(b)\leq g_1(b)\leq 1, g_1(0) \leq 0\}$

with
\begin{align*}
f(b,s) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & (b,s) \in A\\
0 & otherwise.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

What properties does $f$ have? Is there even a way to fully characterize the class of functions $f$ satisfying the monotonicity constraints on $f_B$ and $f_S$?

There seems to be a connection to (algebraic) topology through the set $B = \{(b, s)\in [0,1]^2\mid f(b, s)=1\}$, too.